# Need backup of New.aspx from derictory "Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I permanently delete my New.aspx page, which need SP 2013 for Custom List creation from user interface.
plese provide me with backup file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking it in your recycle bin, there are two recycle bins

1.End User recycle bin
2.Site Collection recycle bin

End User Recycle Bin

Click the Recycle Bin link below the Quick Launch menu.
On the Recycle Bin page, check the boxes next to items that you want to restore (or remove).
Click the Restore Selection link to restore the item(s) or the Delete Selection link to send the item(s) to the site collection Recycle Bin.
Click OK

Site Collection Recycle Bin

Click the Site Actions menu and the select Site Settings.
Under the Site Collection Administration heading, select Recycle Bin
Note: You must be in the root site of the site collection to see this link. If you are not, first select Go to top level site settings. This will bring you to the site settings page of the root site.
The site collection Recycle Bin has two views. Choose the appropriate view on the left of the screen.
End user Recycle Bin items - displays items deleted by all users of the site.
Deleted from end user Recycle Bin - displays items that have been removed from end user Recycle Bins.
Check the box next to the item(s) to be recovered.
Click Restore Selection to restore the item(s).
Click OK

Let me know if you found it..

Comment: I rewrite New.aspx page with my custom New.aspx when I put it in visual studio solution and deploy it. So I need only 1 file, please just give me url where I can download it.

Comment: I have already found this file.please  use following link to download it. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E46D67050409232B%21248